# C++ : Polymorphism and operator overloading

Tags: c++, pointers, comparison, polymorphism, operator-overloading

i am having troubles figuring out how overload comparison operators have to be done when i am using an abstract base class. The main problem is to achieve polymorphism using that base class, since it's abstract it can't be instantiated so i am forced to use a pointer to that base class in order to access the derived class methods. 
I'll put some code in order to describe the situation better :

```
template <typename _Tp>
class Base 
{
    private: 
       _Tp attr ; 
    public: 
       foo() = 0 ; 
       friend bool operator == ( Base* b1, Base* b2)  
       {
           return ( b1.attr == b2.attr ) ;
       }
}; 

template <typename _Tp> class Derived_1 : public Base<_Tp> { /.../ } ;
template <typename _Tp> class Derived_2 : public Base<_Tp> { /.../ } ; 

int main (void)
{
    vector<Base*<int> > * v = new vector<Base*<int> > (2,0) ; 
    v[0] = new Derived_1 () ; 
    v[1] = new Derived_2 () ; 
    if ( (*v)[0] == (*v)[1] ) { /.../ }
    return 0 ;
}
```

So, at this point you will notice that `(*v)[0] == (*v)[1]` its a pointer comparison of `Base*`. I want to know if there is a way to overload the comparison operator between these two pointers, since the overloaded operator that is defined in the base class is never used.

**Edit after responses:**

Since in my real code, the comparison must be `(*v)[0] == (*v)[1]` i can not compare the objects because my data structure would lose generality. Thus, what i am trying to ask you is this:

Can the comparison of `Base` pointers be done? How?

I'm getting errors from the compiler telling me :

> bool operator == (Base*,Base*) must have an argument of class or enumerated type.

Comment: Stop dynamically allocating vectors. There is almost no need to ever do that.

Comment: That's not the problem... remember that's just an example i chose to make you see what i'm trying to ask.

Comment: If your question is simply *"Can I overload a comparison operator that takes 2 Base pointers?"*, then the answer is simple.  No.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Then, how do you do to use polymorphism in structures like a heap that needs this operator overloading?

Comment: @GonzoRI: I was beginning to type a comment response to that, but it got too long, so I will add it to my answer. Give me a minute.

Comment: @andre The reason to allocate dinamically vectors or any large data structure is to get the class object smaller as it can be, then the objects that it(the data structure) uses to work aren't allocated in one block all together but are allocated on different positions at the heap.

Comment: @GonzoRI The vector stores all its data on the heap already! All standard library containers store data on the heap not the stack. Making vector a pointer doesn't save you much and creates issues like the memory leak you have.

Comment: @andre you're right, i was thinking in the one i've implemented that is already a vector of pointers, i implemented that way in order to avoid a lot of objects being allocated contiguously in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Boost Pointer Container Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html)

```
#include <boost/ptr_container/ptr_vector.hpp>
...

int main()
{
    boost::ptr_vector<Base> v;
    v.push_back(new Derived_1);
    v.push_back(new Derived_2);

    if (v[0] == v[1]) { std::cout << "success\n"; }
}
```

If you want to store polymorphic objects in a container that that uses comparison, the Boost Pointer Container Library also has `ptr_set`, `ptr_map`, `ptr_multiset` and `ptr_multimap`.  However, you mentioned a heap.  There is no `boost::ptr_priority_queue`.  In that case, you can just provide your own comparator to `std::priority_queue`.

```
struct BasePtrComp
{
    bool operator()(Base const* lhs, Base const* rhs) const
    {
        return *lhs < *rhs;
    }
};

...

std::priority_queue<Base*, std::vector<Base*>, BasePtrComp> v;
```

Although I would recommend you use smart pointers here instead.

Answer (score 2):

The reason the base class `operator==` is never invoked is because the line

```
v[0] == v[1]
```

compares two pointers - the contents of the vector at index 0 and index 1.

You could change it to be `*v[0] == *v[1]`, which will use the base class operator for comparison.

However, using overloaded operators in a polymorphic setting is fraught with difficulty. For more info on that, look up what Scott Meyers has to say in "Effective C++".

Answer (score 0):

So what you want is to compare object attributes inside pointer comparison, in that case you need to overload pointer's operator==, or ineger. That's not the way it works, since you need to have some kind of "instanceOf" when comparing ints, but these are not always pointers.

Comment: When i try to do the overloading i get a compilation error that i can not solve.

Comment: Maybe because what you are trying to do is bool operator==(int,int)